# Align Main Slider image to center

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm working on a small project, and have one little problem that I don't know how to resolve myself. I have an image gallery with many images, but I want the active image to be centered, without changing the resolution or width/height ratio. Link for the issue [here](https://echographie-sans-frontieres.com/staging/gallery-item/gallery/). Login is `user` / `password`. I tried to manipulate with this CSS:

```
.img {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

However, it seems to ruin the bottom slider. What should I do to center the main image without changing the image ratio? This example image shows what I want to do.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
.flex-active-slide {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.imgs {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right auto;
}
```

or you could do this

```html
<div class="imgs" align="center">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" />
</div>
```