# Move Gallery to center of page in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Recently i have posted question about that how to position my gallery to center, and got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258576/allign-main-slider-image-to-center) from many members. Today replicated the site, and started to work on [another fork site](http://spas-hammam.com/wp/gallery-item/health-counseling/) similar like previous one, with the same theme. I used the same CSS, like in previous thread:

```
.flex-active-slide {
 text-align: center;
}
```

but seems that dont make any changes. i checked the CSS classes, from first site and second one, and its a little different, so i apply this CSS:

```
.col-lg-6 {width:100%;}
.flex-active-slide {
 text-align: center;
}
```

But dont see any change. Some help?

EDIT: this is entire CSS class for that element:

```
    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="gallery-single-post clearfix">
                                    <div class="clearfix" id="slider">

                                            <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><ul class="slides" style="width: 1200%; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
            <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 555px; float: left; display: block;"><a href="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-31.jpg" title=""><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-31-670x500.jpg" alt="gallery-3" draggable="false"></a></li><li style="width: 555px; float: left; display: block;"><a href="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-11.jpg" title=""><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-11-670x500.jpg" alt="gallery-1" draggable="false"></a></li><li style="width: 555px; float: left; display: block;"><a href="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-41.jpg" title=""><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-41-670x500.jpg" alt="gallery-4" draggable="false"></a></li><li style="width: 555px; float: left; display: block;"><a href="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-5.jpg" title=""><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-5-670x500.jpg" alt="gallery-5" draggable="false"></a></li><li style="width: 555px; float: left; display: block;"><a href="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-6.jpg" title=""><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-6-670x500.jpg" alt="gallery-6" draggable="false"></a></li><li style="width: 555px; float: left; display: block;"><a href="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-7.jpg" title=""><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-7-670x500.jpg" alt="gallery-7" draggable="false"></a></li>        </ul></div><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a class="flex-prev flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a></li><li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li></ul></div>
                                                                            <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">

                                        <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><ul class="slides" style="width: 1200%; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                                                <li style="width: 89px; float: left; display: block;" class="flex-active-slide"><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-31-111x69.jpg" alt="gallery-3" draggable="false"></li><li style="width: 89px; float: left; display: block;"><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-11-111x69.jpg" alt="gallery-1" draggable="false"></li><li style="width: 89px; float: left; display: block;"><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-41-111x69.jpg" alt="gallery-4" draggable="false"></li><li style="width: 89px; float: left; display: block;"><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-5-111x69.jpg" alt="gallery-5" draggable="false"></li><li style="width: 89px; float: left; display: block;"><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-6-111x69.jpg" alt="gallery-6" draggable="false"></li><li style="width: 89px; float: left; display: block;"><img src="http://spas-hammam.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/gallery-7-111x69.jpg" alt="gallery-7" draggable="false"></li>                                            </ul></div><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a class="flex-prev flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a></li><li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li></ul></div>
                                                                        </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's inline styling being applied to the slide container from your previous question which is floating the entire slider left. Because of this, you need to make sure the width of the slider is 100%, otherwise `text-align:center;` won't have any effect. Try adding `width:100%!important;` to `.flex-active-slide` as well.

Comment: Just added `width:100%;` to `.flex-active-slide` but dont see changes when reload gallery page.

Comment: Please provide the code necessary to recreate the issue

Comment: Looks like it's what I thought. Each `li` is getting an inline style of `width:555px;` try doing `width:100%!important` to override that style.

Comment: Added `!important` to width, but page seems weird. Pls reload the page to see effect.

Comment: The issue seems to be stemming from the fact that your slider is within a `col-lg-6`, which is a 50% width column. Is there a reason why you're using `col-lg-6` rather than `col-lg-12`? If you want to continue to use `col-lg-6` you will have to override the `max-width:50%` and `flex:0 0 50%;` properties as well.

Comment: Updated `col-lg-6` to `col-lg-12` and now seems fine, except images small slides bellow main image. left and right pointers not works now.